# Can I use a ReferenceBrowserWidget within a Plone 4 portlet?

Tags: python, plone, portlet, widget

I'm creating a new portlet for our Plone 4 site, part of that portlet is a link to an internal page, is there any way I can use a `ReferenceBrowserWidget` to do this?

I suspect the answer is likely to be "no" because the `ReferenceBrowserWidget` is `Archetype-based` content types, whereas the portlets use `zope.schema`...

A note-so ideal method of using an `UberSelectionWidget` (which allows the user to search for content and then select it) works, but I'd really like the users to be able to select the page directly.

Does anyone know how I might be able to achieve this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: The implementation of portlets does not affect the content of portlets, so I don't see any reason why not.

Comment: @Tony: I'm afraid I agree with your reasoning, Plone is stuck with too many mutually incompatible widget systems.